# run Oracle RMAN scripts as a single entry

Tags: c#, oracle, command-line, rman

I want to run an oracle online backup through the rman setup in 12c. I have 3 scripts that need to be run and they are:

- `rman target sys@[db_name]/[db_password] nocatalog`
- `configure channel device type disk clear;`
- `RUN {
    ALLOCATE CHANNEL c1 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Backup\%U';
    BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
  }`

I want to be able to run them as a single entry through a c# `Process` object. I want to emulate using a command line and not a batch file.

So, I've looked at a few questions/answers and have used `&&` to try and combine the commands but that didn't quite work. It took the first two commands and connected me to the RMAN center but the `RUN` command didn't execute (most likely because of the `;` within that part of the script).

**EDIT* - actually only the first command was run. The second did not execute.**

My question: Is there a way that I can combine these 3 script items into 1 to run through the c# `Process.Start()` method?

Comment: Have you tried to put the commands in a command file or use stored scripts?

Comment: I had not at the time. I never could get it to run all as one line in a C# `Process`. Ended up storing the 2nd and 3rd in a `.rman` file and the first in a `.bat` file which called the `.rman` file and that worked so I went with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created two different files.

the first file was a batch file that contained:

- `rman target sys@[db_name]/[db_password] runRman.rman`

The second was a RMAN file called `runRman.rman` which contained:

- `configure channel device type disk clear;`
- `RUN {
  ALLOCATE CHANNEL c1 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Backup\%U';
  BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;`
  }

the c# process called the batch file, which in turn called the rman file and everything worked for me after that.